# Show current datetime-local in input tag in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I want to fill input tag with current dateTime in dateTime-local format
in html.blade.php file.
I want to use somthing like this:

```
<input type="datetime-local"
       autocomplete="on"
       id="created_date"
       name="created_date"
       class="form-control"
       value="{{currentDateTime()}}" >
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use something like this in value parameter

```
<input type="text" value="{{Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d')."T".Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('H:i')}}" />
```

Comment: Using `Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d\TH:i')` is slightly shorter